# jquery-ui distribution file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gruntjs

I started using grunt to compile my assets, instead of loading with `<script>`.
I load it like this:

```
var libraries = [
    /* jQuery */
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",

    /* jQuery UI */
    "node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js",
}
```

And

```
concat: {
    options: {
        stripBanners: true,
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
        '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */',
    },
    js_libs: {
        src: libraries,
        dest: 'dist/js/libs.js'
    }
}
```

Loading jquery-ui, because I could not find a normal distribution file, it throws on console:

> libs.js?version=1461946469:9844 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is
>   not defined

And that line of code is:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
```

1. Is there a distribution file for jquery-ui?
2. If not, how can I make this code work?

Comment: Is there an order to your loading? Perhaps UI is loading before jQuery?

Comment: Also look here for all the files: https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: @Twisty Thanks, that is the distribution file. Do you know if I can find it on npm?

Comment: First hit on Google: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui

Comment: Also: https://blog.jqueryui.com/

Comment: @Twisty I know this package, but it has no distribution files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery-UI has no distribution files in their package.

A better way here, is to use `webpack` to build a single minified uglified bundle file.